# how to get id from url to add it in database as a foreign key in another table

Tags: laravel

i want to get id form url and use it as a foreign key to put it in table in database
when i do it like that a got an error that tour_id column is embty

```
    public function addtour(Request $request,$id) {
    $form_data = array(

        'user_id' =>  $request->input("user_id",auth::user()->id),
        'tour_id' => $request->input("tour_id",$id),
               );
    tecket::create($form_data);
    return view('submit_tour');
}
```

Comment: can you put on the whole error message here?

Comment: it wasnt an error just refreshing the page but i did know what was wrong thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to define a `route` that has the `id` as a `parameter`, so something like:

```
Route::get('/add-tour/{id}', [TourController::class, 'addTour']);  // Laravel 8
Route::get('/add-tour/{id}', 'TourController@addTour'); // Laravel 7
```

The `{id}` parameter in the `URL` will be passed in as the `$id` in your `addTour` function.

What you then do with the `$id` such as checking it is valid is up to you.

Comment: yeah i wrote it like that thanks  i just missed spell word tour in my model thanks